# complicated json to df

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have 100 url and when I click it, it will show json file.
But the json file is a little bit complicated, it looks like this:

```
{
  "release": [
    {
     "id":"1234",
     "version":"1.0",
     "releaseDate":"2023-07-31",
     "xxx": "ssss",
     "yyy": "uuuu" }
    {
     "id" :"2345",
     "version": "1.1"
     "releaseDate":"2023-05-12"
     "xxx":"sssss"
      .....}
],
"user":false
}
```

**I want to count the release for past 6 month,** but the complicated json makes the popular json.loads...pd.read_json...normalize...doesnot work

**also** the .... actually contains some html label like below, so it will be better to just select the "releaseDate" to filter.

```
"att":"<p><em>as Alice</em> for.....
```

**What I tried**

I can use this to count the release for all time

```
releases=len(json_data['releases'])
```

**but how can I limit it to the past 6 month?**
any help is really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Create a string that contains the date from six months ago:

```
six_months_ago = "2023-02-28"
```

And then use `len()` with a list comprehension that only chooses items that were released on or after that date:

```
releases = len([r for r in json_data["releases"] if r["releaseDate"] >= six_months_ago])
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```py
import json

json_string = r"""{
  "release": [
    {
     "id":"1234",
     "version":"1.0",
     "releaseDate":"2023-07-31",
     "xxx": "ssss",
     "yyy": "uuuu" },
    {
     "id" :"2345",
     "version": "1.1",
     "releaseDate":"2023-05-12",
     "xxx":"sssss"},
    {
     "id" :"485",
     "version": "1.2",
     "releaseDate":"2022-05-12",
     "xxx":"sssss"}
],
"user":false
}"""

data = json.loads(json_string)

df = pd.DataFrame(data["release"])
df["releaseDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["releaseDate"], dayfirst=False)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     id version releaseDate    xxx   yyy
0  1234     1.0  2023-07-31   ssss  uuuu
1  2345     1.1  2023-05-12  sssss   NaN
2   485     1.2  2022-05-12  sssss   NaN
```

---

Then to filter this dataframe you can do:

```py
now_minus_6_months = pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.DateOffset(months=6)
print(df[df["releaseDate"] > now_minus_6_months])
```

Prints:

```
     id version releaseDate    xxx   yyy
0  1234     1.0  2023-07-31   ssss  uuuu
1  2345     1.1  2023-05-12  sssss   NaN
```

Comment: I got a url, so I add one request.get before the json.loads, it looks like this: 
json_string = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username,password),verify=False).json()
df = json.loads(json_string)
and then it shows error: "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict", I am so sorry but can I know how to fix that?

Comment: @xlxdxf Try instead `json_string = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username,password),verify=False).text` (note the `.text` at the end)